# Newbie formatting dygraphs fail

Tags: formatting

I am using [arris-capture](https://github.com/graysky2/arris-capture) which makes use of dygraphs for displaying data. The author has kindly provided example data files and an index.html but it is very basic. I have two questions:

1) When I mouse-over any of the graphs, the popup is not formatted nicely. I cannot post an example image because this is my first post. How can I modify the index.html to display the popup that isn't a run on sentence?

I think it would look nicer like this:

```
2013/08/12 18:24:01
Downstream 1: value
Downstream 2: value
Downstream 3: value
Downstream 4: value
Downstream 5: value
Downstream 6: value
Downstream 7: value
Downstream 8: value
```

2) The plots included are pretty basic. I would be very interested to see how some of your dygraph wizards might modify them to be more visually pleasing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of things you can do to format the legend.
Check out the documentation [here](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#Legend).

To get the legend onto separate lines, use `labelsSeparateLines`.
To put the legend somewhere else entirely, use `labelsDiv`.
To completely change the style of the legend, use `labelsDivStyles`